# Total a row of cells if not blank, and their equivalent in different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula, where I currently have April - September Budget for sales, and equivalent April - September Sales.

The budget figures are fixed, the Sales figures automatically populate when input in a different tab within the spreadsheet.

I need to total the budget YTD figures (in yellow highlight - R6) [Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvP01.png), when the sales figures are populated, only for the months applicable. So, in my example, there are figures for April and May, therefore the formula would generate the total budget figures stated for April and May.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
=SUMIF(RC[-7]:RC[-2],"> 0",RC[-15]:RC[-9])
```